# How to alter Child Component HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, material-design, angular-material

I have following issue:

I have a Datatable from *Angular Material*. Now, I want to implement a feature where I can choose one row of the table and drag it into another part of the application.

In *HTML* it's easy, with the `draggable="true"` parameter, which I can add to any tag.

However, I don't know the row tags, and can't access them, since *Angular Material* generates it.

How can I accomplish it? Is it possible to access the component with `ViewChild` and then add the `draggable` parameter to every row tag in the Material Table Component?

Or any best practice? Because I think it will always be an issue to customize *Angular Material* components.

Comment: Did you try on the `mat-row` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mat-row` attribute.

```
<mat-row draggable="true" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

**[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5jf8nt?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**

Comment: Thank you. However I need to clarify a bit, we use Alfresco ADF, which then uses Material Design. So I don't have access to mat-row :D. Sorry, but I just thought it would be enough, I just need to know, whats the best way to attack this.

Comment: See, that's why you post code when you ask a question.